# Is there a way to sync or update Wattpad reading progress on Goodreads?

Tags: ebook-readers, ebook-management, android, sync

Can the [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/home) reading progress be synced on [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/)? If not officially, I would be interested also in a workaround, since Wattpad does not have page numbers for doing so.

It updates the progress of the ebooks in terms of pre-calculated time taken, rather than page numbers or percentages like Kindle.